# Visual Studio 2013 - navigating among many projects

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, solution-explorer

Complex solutions usually contains several projects.

Currently I have more than 30 projects in a solution.

Some of the projects could contain many files inside (up to 1000 or more).

So when you open files from different projects all this stuff is expanded.
So if I want to find some file using solution explorer I need to scroll forever until it will be found.

Of course it is possible to navigate to it using Resharper's Ctrl+T but this is not related to those files you don't remember names but remember in which project and in which folder it is located.

I've tried to find some extension which could create tabs from projects but unfortunately unsuccessfully.
So is there any way to effectively navigate in such scenarios?

Comment: My company uses Visual Assist (http://www.wholetomato.com). Alt+Shift+O opens a dialog with all files in the solution. Works fine on solution with >150 projects.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

- Organize files into folders so that you don't have more than a few folders open when working on any given feature
- Forget files; instead, navigate to class by name. Ctrl+, is the default shortcut.
- Use F12 to go to definition; this also avoids having to find the file.
- Search by keyword. Ctrl+Shift+F finds in all files. You just need to remember *something* from the file; it doesn't have to be the file name.
- Enable "Track Active Item in Solution Explorer" in Options / Projects & Solutions / General. This keeps the file that is being edited selected in the solution explorer (but does lead to lots of folders expanding all the time).
- Conversely, *disable* "Track Active Item", then you'll be in charge of what folders are expanded. Try both, see which one works best.
- Use Solution Folders, which enable you to place several projects into a folder.

Comment: Use everything among that. Thank you anyway!